# Is once a "too broad" question remains always a "too broad" question (even after edits)?

Tags: support, closed-questions

### TL;DR

I had posted a question: [How can free will really exist if universe repeats itself in perfect pattern?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/32768/19246) which orginally looked exactly like [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10911/1049).

Despite of great trimming down, it's still in the closed state with "too broad" stamp. I believe `[on hold]` postfix is meant for those question which are potential for opening.
Why my question is not opening?

### Detailed

I am a seasoned SO contributor in form of Q&A. Being aware of most of the guidelines, I do understand that there are small changes from community to community. Having a question in mind for a while, I posted in parallel by just copy pasting in 2 communities: "Hinduism" and "Philosophy".

- In "Hinduism" because, I am regular visitor there and there are
  certain aspects of the questions which are having foundation in
  scriptures.
- In "Philosophy" as my 1st query, because there was certain logic &
  reasoning in it with philosophical representation of time; Also this
  community is broader than other religion based communities

However, instead of meeting with good response on the Q, it turned out to be hostile. The Q was downvoted and closed in a short while.

Following efforts were put to let this question remain opened:

- The first commenter, who also voted for closing suggested that there
  should not be too many Qs and meta info. Though it didn't make sense
  for me to copy paste this same Q many times to ask each aspect
  separately, I compromised by reducing the Qs to only 2 from 4! Be aware that, in last line I had also mentioned that, if the theory is proved otherwise then none out 4 Qs to be answered.
- Still the moderator rejected and told that I am confused due to
  still too many Qs. Hence I strike-through all the 4 questions and
  just asked only 1 which was in title
- The moderator was not happy with the strike-through. My intention was
  to make the content visible in subtle manner. However I removed
  strike-through and asked moderator to either reopen or suggest
  further improvement; But haven't received any response so far
- Apparently a user pointed out a [similar
  question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/the-eternal-return-as-thought-experiment-what-are-the-consequences)
  which was well received and was not closed; Even though the answer it
  was seeking was bit broad (at least to me)

For now, I have flagged this question for moderator attention; But almost after 12 hours, there is no resolution.

**Update**: Seems that the flag to reopen post even after all the edits is declined. Surprisingly someone has downvoted this Q too! Anyways, this is the max I could do to bring the problem to notice.

This seems like a club, where people have to dance differently on a same music record daily.
:-)

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

12 hours does not seem like a long time at least to me for us to think about whether what's there is now on-topic.

## Further Thoughts

But there are some things you're posting here that suggest other reasons your question should be closed.

## Cross Posting

You're not supposed to post essentially the same question in multiple SEs. Or at least that's how I read the following:

[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

[Cross-posting etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette)

The hinduism SE has not given an answer yet -- though they've upvoted it. Maybe this is a key issue in Hinduism for which they are better suited to answer?

## Possible Duplicate

The question you mention ([The eternal return, as thought experiment: what are the consequences?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/the-eternal-return-as-thought-experiment-what-are-the-consequences)) is a question you were referred to as a being a "possible duplicate." So even if your question *would have been* on-topic at some point in the past, that it has been answered would mean it is no longer.

## Personal Philosophy

You state in a comment "Yes, my post in a way proves the non-existence of "free will" but there are certain moral implications because of that."

But we're not here to check people's proofs of their own ideas. We're here to answer questions about philosophy.

## Misunderstanding Philosophy

I am not following you when you refer to philosophy.SE as "this community is broader than other religion based communities." That would seem to imply that is or should be a "religion based community"

> Is this a club, where people dance differently on same music record daily?

No. But it is a completely volunteer activity on the part of its members.  Philosophy differs pretty markedly from say the main SE in that it has to be even more careful with how it manages what sorts of questions to allow.

Specifically, the main criteria is do you ask a question about philosophy broadly construed that could have a correct answer? In the case of your question, there seems to be a decent amount of background legwork (reading your answers in other places, etc.) Can you remove all the background legwork? And then if you do that, what's left that's a single question *about philosophy?* that' answerable within the bounds of an SE.

## Misunderstanding a Question Close

> However, instead of meeting with good response on the Q, it turned out to be hostile. The Q was downvoted and closed in a short while.

Closing a question is not a "hostile" action. It's a response to things that do not meet our community guidelines.

None of this bodes well for the question being a good fit for philosophy.SE.

Comment: Lots of things are written here, but it doesn't convey anything except justification of wrongful closure. Neither it's a duplicate of any other post nor am I asking to verify my own philosophy. The linked answer in that post is not for BG legwork. It's just that I don't want people to bring arguments which are already discussed. As a moderator, we expect you to help improving the posts when the user is actively editing to make it useful. What I see that, you have taken that Q too personally and finding out reasons to keep it closed for eternity. I also see that the flag to reopen is declined.

Comment: "The linked answer in that post is not for BG legwork. It's just that I don't want people to bring arguments which are already discussed." **Please reread the pair of sentences in your comment here.** You want people to be aware of what you've already discussed = BG legwork.